# Windows10のAutoHotkeyで、「Ctrl」キーを押しながら「Windowsマーク」キー、あるいは「Alt」キーを押しながら「無変換」キーをどう書きますか？

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

Windows10 AutoHotkey コードの下記部分を

```
^a::
```

- 「Ctrl」キーを押しながら「Windowsマーク」キー
- 「Alt」キーを押しながら「無変換」キー

上記いずれかへ変更したいのですが、それぞれどう書けばよいですか？

Comment: AutoHotkey は使った事が無いので分かりませんが、Ctrl と Windows キーはそれぞれ別のキーと組み合わせて使う [修飾キー](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BF%AE%E9%A3%BE%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC) なので、修飾キーのみの組み合わせはいまいちな気がします。

Comment: これらのヘルプ記事から探して試してみてはどうでしょう？ [ホットキー](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/Hotkeys), [キーリスト](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/KeyList), [Send / SendRaw / SendEvent / SendInput / SendPlay](https://sites.google.com/site/autohotkeyjp/reference/commands/Send)